# Solarium Exception in core php

Tags: php, solarium

I use Solarium on `php` on this website: http://dothejob.in/telamela-new/.

When I choose any sub category this error will be displayed on the page.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Solarium\Exception\HttpException'
>
> with message 'Solr HTTP error: HTTP request failed, couldn't connect
>   to host'
>
> in
>   /home/apurav/telamela/pro/vendor/solarium/solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Adapter/Curl.php:248
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 /home/apurav/telamela/pro/vendor/solarium/solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Adapter/Curl.php(123):
>
> Solarium\Core\Client\Adapter\Curl->check('', Array, Resource id #167)
>
> #1 /home/apurav/telamela/pro/vendor/solarium/solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Adapter/Curl.php(99):
>
> Solarium\Core\Client\Adapter\Curl->getResponse(Resource id #167,
>   false)
>
> #2 /home/apurav/telamela/pro/vendor/solarium/solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Adapter/Curl.php(83):
>
> Solarium\Core\Client\Adapter\Curl->getData(Object(Solarium\Core\Client\Request),
>   Object(Solarium\Core\Client\Endpoint))
>
> #3 /home/apurav/telamela/pro/vendor/solarium/solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Client.php(814):
>
> Solarium\Core\Client\Adapter\Curl->execute(Object(Solarium\Core\Client\Request),
>   Object(Solarium\
>
> in
>   /home/apurav/telamela/pro/vendor/solarium/solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Adapter/Curl.php
>
> on line 248

Comment: _couldn't connect to host_ should be quite clear...

Comment: how to resolve this . explain it

Comment: Make sure that your Solr endpoint config is proper and that Solr endpoint is up and running. http://wiki.solarium-project.org/index.php/V3:Basic_usage